# Can’t get my volume button to work at all

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, sound-volume

Recently my MacBook Air stopped allowing me to adjust the volume. Whether I press <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd> it shows a *forbidden* symbol on it, as in the picture below.

[image: Volume Forbidden]

After some research I discovered there is a mute button in System Preferences, and you are supposed to make sure that it isn’t muted. However I don’t have the option to unmute it.

[image: No output devices found]

Anyone know what to do in this case? I’ve restarted the computer several times but that didn’t fix anything.

Comment: Are you sure your speakers weren't damages in any way?

Comment: Seems to be a somewhat known glitch with the Air, some more discussion here that might help: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1736638?start=345&tstart=0

Comment: In the picture, it just shows the desktop and the command window - no menu bar, dock, or files on the desktop. Did you hide those for the purpose of this question, or are you logged into your computer differently?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with other macs. [Resetting my PRAM](https://thenextweb.com/lifehacks/2017/06/14/how-when-why-to-reset-the-pram-smc-on-your-mac/)  by pressing command + option + p+ r during reboot fixed the problem for me